# Automating installing wished to use wait or wait_not or cpu_uasge_lower to wait for my last screen to popup

Tags: pywinauto

I am working on my python file and automating an installation of various applications. I have to wait till my installation is completed and then click on few buttons and till now my program is working fine and I am using `time.sleep()`. But I wanted to use wait/waitNot, so that it is not time dependent.
For example: I have pressed button "Install" and it took 20 seconds for my installation to complete. I have used `time.sleep(20)` but this is not the same for installation on all PCs. Therefore I wish to use `wait` or `wait_not`.
I have used `app.wait('enabled')`, but this didn't help. Help me out on this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the docs chapter: [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html). Please be careful which object has which methods. `.wait('visible', timeout=20)` is a method of WindowSpecification. Maybe read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) first if you haven't read it yet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help! I wanted to ask can i perform more complex tasks like change the system configuration like disabling firewall or changing ip-address of the PC using this Pywinauto.

Comment: Changing IP address can be done by `netsh` command without any GUI automation. Not sure about firewall. I'm not an IT engineer / sysadmin.